# Python - How can this return -1?

Tags: python, pypy

Should it be possible for this method to return -1?

```
def tree_value(self, team, x, y):
    if team == NO_TEAM or self.team_sees_tree[team, x, y]:
        return int(self.tree[x, y])
    else:
        return TREE_NONE
```

Set up:

```
import numpypy as np

TREE_NONE = 255
NO_TEAM = -1

self.tree= np.empty((dim, dim), np.uint8)
    for i in xrange(dim):
        for j in xrange(dim):
            self.tree[i, j] = TREE_NONE
    self.team_sees_tree = np.zeros((16, dim, dim), np.bool_)
```

During normal operation, tree values are set to 0-15 (team number) or TREE_NONE (255). Even if they were accidentally set to -1 (NO_TEAM), that should equate to 255 as a uint8.

Call to tree_value() that gets the -1:

```
data = [(self.Tiles.tree_value(COLOR_NONE, x, y),
    self.Tiles.mountain_value(x, y)) for (x, y) in coords]
str = ""
try:
    for (t, m) in data:
        str += chr(t) + chr(m)
except ValueError as e:
    print data
        # [(255, 0), (255, 0), (255, 0), (255, 0), (255, 0), (-1, 0), (255, 0)]
    print e
        # ValueError: character code not in range(256)
```

Can't accurately reproduce this problem, but my server is hitting it about twice an hour. Running PyPy recent nightly build (pypy-c-jit-64927-e0ba4acfd3c2-linux.tar.bz2) on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.

Comment: Since this seems like at least possibly a bug in NumPyPy, can you please include the NumPyPy version?

Comment: Version: e0ba4acfd3c2

Comment: I should also note that the data (the nparrays) are loaded from a pickled file made on a Windows box with a slightly earlier pypy version. Could this be a problem?

Comment: ^ Now using pickled files from the same version of PyPy. Problem still occurring.

Comment: Well, I guess the first step should be to dump out the whole array and see if it shows anything odd, which would completely rule out anything related to the pickling/unpicking. But I can't imagine what it could store in a `uint8` cell that would cause it to return -1 instead of 255…

Comment: For now I've added extra checks for -1. Hope this is fixed in a more complete version of PyPy. Just wanted to sanity check that I wasn't missing a bug in this code.

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in NumPyPy rather than PyPy (especially given the maturity of the two projects). But either way, you probably want to search both bug bases, try to come up with a good repro case to file, send a message to the mailing list, etc. It's probably a trivial problem where they mix up uint8 and int8 somewhere, but until someone has a test case to track down where that somewhere is, nobody's going to fix it…

Comment: PyPy developer here: yes, I agree completely with abarnert.  Please report it as a bug with a way to reproduce, even if we need to run ourselves an example program for a couple of hours.

Comment: Simplified and reported at: https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1578

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in PyPy; it was really a bug (see https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1578).  The code in one rarely-executed path was forgetting about unsigned integers, and so always reading the byte as a signed value.  More precisely, this code was in the JIT tracer. That's why it gave a bogus result only once, with all previous results correct (computed by the interpreter), and all following results correct as well (computed by the assembler that we just generated).